# Xamarin (Android) Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, unit-testing, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop Xamarin Android application. I want to add simple unit tests of logic only. For that purpose, I tried adding "Unit Test App (Android)" or "Class Library (Android)" projects with unit tests and none of them work.

## Unit Test App (Android)

I add new project to my solution of type "Unit Test App (Android)". Generated project contains `TestsSample` class with sample tests, but I have no idea how to launch them. I have ReSharper installed, but when right clicking on the project/class I don't have option to run the tests.
When I go to "Test" -> "Run" -> "All tests", the solution is built, but nothing more happens.

## Class Library (Android) with nUnit

The other trial was to add new project of type "Class Library (Android)" to the solution. After, I installed nUnit nuget package (`install-package nunit` which installed package 'nunit.3.6.1' with respect to project 'MoneyBack.Tests', targeting 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0'), installation was successful.

I added the following class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MoneyBack.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void SampleTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when right-clicking on the tests project I see ReSharper's option "Run Unit Tests", so I clicked it and got the following exception:
[image: TargetInvocationException]

Am I doing something wrong ? Or it's the issue with VS2017 ? I don't know if I should install VS2015 back or there is some solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A `Unit Test App (Android)` project needs to be run on a device/emulator as it requires the `Xamarin.Android` framework to run. Also `NUnit 2.6.x` is required.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exception here rather than posting a screen shot.

Comment: I can't copy-paste this exception, it's a window in which there is no TextBox... @SushiHangover even though it requires emulator, it should launch it, not throw exception, right ? BTW, I only want to test my platform-independent logic, do I always need to run tests on the device ? Even if yes, I cannot do it..

Comment: @DawidSibinski Platform-**independent** logic tests should go in standard/PCL NUnit/XUnit/... test projects. As far as your `Unit Test App (Android) project`, set an Android device/emulator target and build/run the application (Resharper does not know anything about Xamarin-specfic device testing).

Comment: @SushiHangover ah, you see, I added "Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)" and it works! Thanks! That's what I was looking for. However, I still cannot launch those tests on the device...

Comment: @DawidSibinski You can reference a `PCL Test project` or native platform library project within an Xamarin Unit Test App (Android or iOS) and include that assembly(ies) to be tested via the `NUnit for Devices` application, then build and target that application onto a device/emulator. Once run, it will present a UI for execution of the referenced [Test] in those assemblies

Comment: @SushiHangover that's cool, write your answer and I'll accept it. Do you know any tutorial/article about unit testing in Android (Xamarin)? To get familiar with all those rules?

Comment: @DawidSibinski See if my answer helps :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are three basic levels of testing:

#### The classic unit testing of pure .Net/Mono code via xUnit|NUnit

- Nothing new here, this is the same testing that .Net programmers have been doing all long and has nothing to do with the Xamarin platform frameworks

Note: These tests are *totally independent* of `Xamarin.Android|iOS|Mac`

#### On platform testing (including platform features)

Note: There are multiple on device testing wrappers for NUnit, XUnit, etc... Xamarin includes a `NUnitLite` version that runs on `Android` and `iOS` and that provide a device specific UI to run those tests. Xamarin has templates that create a **`Unit Test App`** project for Android or iOS.

Note: These tests can include platform dependent features (Networking, Bluetooth, GPS, SMS, etc... but no GUI related tests) and can also reference Nunit `[Test]`s written in PCL-based assemblies or platform-specific libraries.

- [`Xamarin.iOS` Unit Testing](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/)
- [`Xamarin.Mac` Unit Testing via `GUIUnit`](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mac/guiunit-example/)
- [`Xamarin.Android` Setup and Automating](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test/)

Alternatives to NUnitLite:

- [xUnit.net Runners for Devices](https://github.com/xunit/devices.xunit)
- [NUnit test runners for Xamarin and mobile devices](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin)

#### UI Testing

A Casabash/Appium/... driven tests of the UI elements in your application and their reaction to input (touch) events.

- Test Cloud/Mobile Center and/or other local, public or private mobile test clouds
- [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/introduction-to-test-cloud/)

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answer :) So for each of those three levels you create a separate project in your solution? What is the best practice in Android - to always have only unit tests of pure .NET/Mono + platform-specific tests project ? Are UI tests common and considered as best practice also ?

Comment: `Are UI tests common and considered as best practice also?` Absolutely yes.... With so many API levels, screen resolutions, memory and device features amount a large number of Android device manufacturers/vendors, UI Testing becomes a strong requirement and should not be overlooked.

Comment: I normally create `Shared Projects` that contain my tests (one for platform specific and one for pure .Net framework tests), I can than include those projects into the platform specific test app in order to re-test my "pure .Net framework" code as there are differences between Mono and .Net (such as `HttpClient`implementations), and I can also shared those tests between iOS, Android, Mac, UWP, etc... test wrappers...

Comment: How much and what you test is up to your project goals and design. I tend to only use MVVM (or VIPER) as a design/code pattern so what is tested in each of those three levels of tests in my answer tend to be fairly nature. When using VIPER-based design we can do Test Driven Development (TDD) on every part of the app below the UI without every writing one line of GUI code as *everything* is mockable. But again, it really is up to how you (& team if any) are designing/coding the app, hopefully testing will not be an afterthought as that lets to bad App Store reviews and mad customers ;-)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your insights. I'm developing an open-source Xamarin.Android app for the programming competition, code is published on GitHub so I want it to be done as it should :)

Comment: @DawidSibinski what is the competition?

Comment: The competition is called DajSiePoznac (EN. "GetNoticed"). You can find more details on my blog: http://www.dsibinski.pl/dajsiepoznac-2017/
My blog is in English where I write about the project and the competition (as writing a blog is one of the competition's goals), so I invite you to see that :)

Answer (score 1):

Test are run from the device itself not directly from the code as we are used to. Do this:
1. set you android project as VS startup project
2. Select the harware or simulator that you want to execute the unit test project
3. Run it
4. The unit test project will be deployed and executed in the device.
5. Tap on the line with the project name. The available tests will appear. Tap each one for execution and debug ! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install nUnit 2.6.X for using xamarin.UItest.
2. nUnit 3 is not supported.