# Cast a Java.Lang.Object to Interface

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I am currently writing an UI Test for an android scanner application.

As I cannot reference my xamarin android project directly in my UI Test because then the scanner services will not build as they are incompatible with the .Net Framework 4.6.1 which is used by the Xamarin.UITest framework.

Therefore I have an interface in my Xamarin.Forms project wrapping the needed class which is implemented by a class inside the Xamarin Android Project and returned through a Export method as you don't have any access to your app runtime in the Xamarin UI Test as it wraps the apk runtime.

Xamarin Forms:

```
public interface IWrapper {
    public WrappedClass { get;}
}
```

Xamarin Android:

```
public class Wrapper: Java.Lang.Object, IWrapper {
    public WrappedClass { get;}
    public Wrapper(WrapperClass wrapperClass){
       this.WrappedClass = wrapperClass;
  }
}
```

Exposed Method:

```
[Export]
public Wrapper GetWrapper(){
     Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(this._app.WrappedClass);
     return Wrapper;
}
```

Xamarin UI Test:

```
[SetUp]
public void BeforeEachTest() {
    //md541ff4e74307b9d66e591e6d9ce55078f.Wrapper@41562080
    object exportObject = this._app.Invoke("GetWrapper");
    // null
    IWrapper wrapper = (IWrapper)exportObject;
    this._appRuntimeWrappeClass = wrapper.WrappedClass;
}
```

Is it even possible to cast the object into a Interface and get access to the underlying runtime object to influence your app?

Comment: I seem only to be able to get a strings as a response which is pretty useless in my usecase.

Comment: Would it be an idea to serialize the data to JSON and deserialize it in your test?

Comment: I also thought about but I need the runtime object to control my application. Would I take the json In/Out way I would be forced to write a complex control /configuration structure.

Comment: @CodeBastard `...the scanner services will not build as they are incompatible...`: I am totally confused, a UITest agent is running on the device/emulator while the NUnit portion should never have access to the scanner process (Java/NDK) . Why not create a backdoor that instructs your "scanner services" to skip the capture/scan portion of your code and just return some mocked barcode data. Call that backdoor at the beginning of any scan-based tests in order to skip that part of the UI.

Comment: That was one possible solution but a implementation of a mock scanner service with a controller for the different test cases would cost me multiple days and I hoped I could make the another solution work. I am currently working on a NUnit 3 based solution no longer aiming for a UI Test but running my tests on the viewModels.

Comment: @CodeBastard Ahhh. you have this tagged as UITest (and in your question you refer to UITest), which is is not then as it should be a "pure" .Net NUnit test with no device/emulator in the mix. If your ViewModels have pulled in any `Xamarin.Android` code, then you need to move that out to the View level or a Service and abstract/mock that in your tests.

Comment: @SushiHangover Every dependency to Xamarin.Android lies in the Xamarin Android app everything else is .net standard 2.0 only except the views which are Xamarin Forms. ViewModels are also .net standard 2.0 only. The problem are the scanner service calls which are made trough an interface but would be all hell to mock for all different states the scanner service can take. You can make this an answer as this seems to be the only vailable solution when using the Xamarin.UITest framework.

Comment: @CodeBastard I do not see a way around mocking out the scanner service if this a NUnit (non-UITest-based *and* non-device based) unless you create your own host<->device(scanner service) bridge, and that is assuming the scanning process is 100% non-interactive. Or if this is a NUnit **On-Device** test (no UITest/no UI interaction) and the ViewModels can 100% drive the scanner service with no-user interaction. Or if this is a UITest, then either you skip the scanning part or mock it. So your three test types; 1) No device&UI, 2) On device/no UI, 3) On device w/UI, which one are you using?

Comment: @SushiHangover my Goal was Nr.2 On device/no UI as I can simulate every UserInteraction with the ViewModels without the UI. As we are running on a crippled 4.2 android scanner with low ram and cpu there is no value to intergration/acceptance/uitest not running on the device. I work now with the NUnit runtime on the device as Xamarin.UITest don't seem to be intended for my testcase. But thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: @CodeBastard https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939217/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks the NUnit runner for android is what I am currently using.