# Unable to create instance of UnitTest class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to test a function from test existing project in xamarin forms. for that i have created a separate project in same solution and trying to call methods from a different project class from test class. then it is showing this error. Please help me to resolve this.

[image]

> Testing1.UnitTest1.
>   Error: System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call
>   Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it

Comment: First off, posting images is bad, you should copy-paste the error (and the code in question!) into your question.
Second, what seems to be the problem? Have you tried, idk, calling `Xamarin.Forms.Init()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939217/4984832

Answer (score 0):

This error is there because you need to mock Xamarin.Forms in your unit test project.

You can use [this nuget package](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/Xamarin.Forms.Mocks) and follow the tutorial in their github. There is also great [article](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/mocking-xamarin-forms) to read.