# Xamarin Android UnitTest and Instrumentation Test (not Forms)

Tags: c#, android, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android

Recently I have implemented UI tests in Xamarin Android [using Xamarin.UITests in version 2.2.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/2.2.4) and [NUnit 2.6.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.4) as they indicate in the [official MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/uitest) to test everything related to the user interface and their respective validations, say, wait for an image to load, a button action, gestures, etc. .. This I did with all the `Fragments` and `Activities` of my Android project and in total I managed to build the structure to successfully execute approximately 300 tests.

The problem is that now **I want to run Unit Tests independent of the UI**, that is, each asynchronous tasks that connect to my web service. I have not succeeded in creating a unit testing project in which I can instantiate a class from my project and execute the methods that are communicated to the WS. I have searched a lot of information for the Android platform in particular, so that by adding the reference of my Android project, I can use the classes freely, but I do not give any results.

For example, after adding the reference of my project: **MyApp.dll**, I can use the classes of it, where I have a `Fragment` called **ProfileFragment.cs** that contains an asynchronous method called `GetProfileAsync()`.

I try to do the following in a test:

```
[Test]
public async void GetProfileTest ()
{
    var profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    var result = await profileFragment.GetProfileAsync();

    Assert.IsNotNull (result);
}
```

However, using the framework of `Xamarin.UITest` or `NUnit for .Net Framework`, I get the following error:

> Message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Mono.Android, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken = 84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system can not find the specified file.

Here are my two questions:

**- Do you have any idea how to test all the asynchronous methods of a class in an Android project in Unit Testing using NUnit Framework?** *I need a guide how to do the setup of a NUnit project so that I can instantiate classes from my MonoAndroid project without receiving this exception.*

**- What am I doing wrong?**

**- Would I need to do these tests on the backend only using NUnit for the .Net Framework?**

**- Should I separate and create the methods of my web services in the NUnit project directly?** *I do not know how maintainable it is, since I have validations for Release mode and Debug mode of my Android project, which, depending on one or the other flame or another, connects to a different host, part of which is a large amount of HTTP GET and POST methods.*

Comment: It seems Visual Studio 2017 on Windows no longer has a template for a **Unit Test App (Android)** project. See this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test , but VS for Mac does have the **Unit Test App** for Android. I'm not sure why that was eliminated in VS 2017 on Windows, but perhaps you can workaround the issue by creating the Android Unit Test project in VS for Mac and then bringing it over to VS on Windows.

Comment: Also worth noting is that an Android Unit test project needs to run on a device or simulator so that the Xamarin.Android framework is available... sounds like you might not have been doing that (also using the wrong project type)?  If you don't want to run unit tests on device or simulator, then you will want to split off you platform agnostic code, like code that accesses your webservice, into a .NET Standard project, and then you can use a .NET Standard unit test project to test those methods.

Comment: Are you trying to do classic N|XUnit testing or on device testing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938447/xamarin-android-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2017/42939217#42939217

Comment: @SushiHangover a classic test, with Android reference as `.dll`. @jgoldberger-MSFT That's right, but I just want to avoid duplicating code, because maintenance will be a disaster. What I am really trying to do is to use the reference of my android project as a .dll in a unit test of NUnit, however when creating an instance of some kind of project (in .dll), like a class I get the exception described in the question.

Comment: Let's suppose the following scenario, if I pass the asynchronous methods as such to my unit test and in the future I make a change of the side of the android project in that method, I want to reflect that change in the project of the test, without needing to do it manually, since that dll is generated or updated with each project build. I'm a newbie on the subject of unit tests. Do you think it's a bad practice or am I right?

Comment: @Andrespengineer You can not have it both ways, either the code your testing requires the Android framework or not. If it does, then you need it running on a device/emulator. Otherwise you or team needs to abstract as much of the code away from Android as possible, *assumably* in a .NetStd library and thus you could perform "classic style testing" on that library without the need for a device/emulator.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT I was able to get what I wanted thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *[@jgoldberger-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2913599/jgoldberger-msft)* and *[@SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover)* for their comments.

In the end I had two options to achieve my goal:

- [xUnit Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/).
- [Xamarin Android Instrumented Tests (NUnitLite)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test).

### Setting up XUnit for Xamarin Android

---

You can run tests on the device with by using [xUnit Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/) and [xUnit.Runner.Devices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.devices/). However, the test package (all your classes of testing and configuration) must be attached to the **current Xamarin Android project in the solution**, so that the reference of the same project (including classes, resources, and the context of the application) can be used satisfactorily. Otherwise, this will generate a lot of endless errors referring to Android resources, because you can not put two applications together.

Once installed both Frameworks mentioned above, just make the configuration of your launch activity as follows:

- At top of your MainLauncher Activity class, define a [Preprocessor Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if): This will allow you to run the application for tests or with normal flow. Note that it has the Debug directive, which will allow you to only execute the condition if the application will deploy in debug.

.

```
 //#define TEST // Uncomment this to start UnitTestig

 . . .

 [ /* Your ActivityAttributes */ ]
 public class YourLauncherActivity : Activity {

      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    #if (DEBUG && TEST)
           // Your TestConfiguration.cs Activity
           Intent iTestConfiguration = new Intent(this, typeof(TestConfiguration));
           StartActivity(iTestConfiguration);
    #endif
    #if !TEST
           // Run your normal Activity here, like Login, etc...
    #endif
            }
        }

    ...
```

Your test setup activity should look something like this: **TestConfiguration.cs**

```
    [Activity(Label = "TestConfiguration")]
    public class TestConfiguration : Xunit.Runners.UI.RunnerActivity
    {
        //public static Context Context { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            // tests can be inside the main assembly
            AddTestAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            AddExecutionAssembly(typeof(ExtensibilityPointFactory).Assembly);
            // or in any reference assemblies   
            //this.AutoStart = true;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            //Context = this;
        }
    }
```

Then define your tests within the project, using [xUnit Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/), for example: **MyTests.cs**

```
public class MyTests
    {

        public MyTests()
        {
            // Before each test
        }


        [Fact]
        public void FailingTest()
        {
            Assert.True(false);
        }
    }
```

Now you can run the tests on the xUnit Runner for Devices Activity that was created.

### Setting up Xamarin Android Instrumentation

---

Now, if you want to run instrumentation test in a Xamarin Android project, you should do the following:

First of all, execute the following tutorial step by step:

- [Instrumentation test in a Xamarin Android project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test)

Once complete, add a static reference to your TestSuiteInstrumentation in the configuration class of your test, for example: **TestInstrumentation.cs**

```
. . .
        public static TestSuiteInstrumentation CurrentInstrumentation { get; set; }

        public TestInstrumentation(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
        {
            CurrentInstrumentation = this;
        }
. . .
```

Now if you want to configure your tests so that you want to run an Activity implicitly and use its views, properties, etc ... You can do the following: Example for my **Login.cs** Activity

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class LoginTests
    {
        private TestSuiteInstrumentation instrument = TestInstrumentation.CurrentInstrumentation;
        private Activity CurrentActivity;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrument.AddMonitor($"{instrument.TargetContext.PackageName}." + nameof(Login), null, false);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            intent.SetClassName(instrument.TargetContext, $"{instrument.TargetContext.PackageName}." + nameof(Login));

            Task.Run(() => instrument.StartActivitySync(intent)).GetAwaiter();

            Activity currentActivity = instrument.WaitForMonitor(monitor);

        }

        [Test]
        public void LoginTest()
        {
            // Verify your activity is not null 
            Assert.NotNull(CurrentActivity);

            // Convert CurrentActivity to your Activity
            Login login = CurrentActivity as Login;


            // Verify your views are not null, finding views in your Activity
            Assert.NotNull(login);
            Assert.NotNull(login.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etLoginUsername));
            Assert.NotNull(login.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etLoginPassword));


            instrument.RunOnMainSync(() => {

                // Here you can run your UI methods or properties for Views, example
                login.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etLoginUsername).Text = "hello";
                login.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etLoginPassword).Text = "world";
            });

            // Here will be your assertions
        }
    }
```

Now run your test with ADB. Following this steps:

- Deploy your application in debug or release mode. Then stop it.
- Locate your instrumentation tests, use the following command:

  `adb shell pm list instrumentation`
- Copy the complete name of the test you want to execute and execute the following command:

  `adb shell am instrument -w /*paste the full name of your instrumentation test*/`

**IMPORTANT:**  Your activity needs to have a defined name in the ActivityAttribute to prevent the **classes.dex** file from finding your class. For example, if my PackageName is `com.yourpackage.android` and my Activity class is **Login.cs** at your `ActivityAttributes` add:

```
[Activity( ... , Name ="com.yourpackage.android.Login", ...)]
```