# Setting up test projects in your solution for a Xamarian app

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin

I have experience unit testing but I have never unit tested a Xamarian solution.

My question is should I add two unit test projects to my solution?  One would be a MSTest or NUnit test that tests the logic and another project Xamarian.UITest that only tests the UI?  From my browsing on the internet it seems the Xamarian.UITest is only able to test the UI?  Is this true or can you test the logic as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin.UITest is only for automation testing. (UI). You cannot test logic behind it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939217/4984832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make Xamarin.UITest test the entire application.  Use Xamarin.UITest to automate the testing of the UI and, providing you have a decent separation of concerns, use xUnit, NUnit, etc, to test the logic part(s) of your app.

Comment: Thanks I kinda figured that but I just wanted confirmation on how to proceed.  Thanks!