# Can not run Unitests with Xamarin

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to check my Xamarin project code (Cookbook) with unit tests. I've created a Unitest for Xamarin project from Visual Studio (UITest1). When I try to run it the linker writes the following error:

```
Error   NU1201  Project Cookbook is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) / win-x64. Project Cookbook supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)    UITest1
```

What am i doing wrong? Tried to Google but with no luck.

This is the Uinitests code if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Cookbook;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace UITest1
{
    [TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
    [TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
    public class Tests
    {
        IApp app;
        Platform platform;
        private Ingredient ingr;

        public Tests(Platform platform)
        {
            this.platform = platform;
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            //app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);

            ingr = new Ingredient();
        }

        [Test]
        public void WelcomeTextIsDisplayed()
        {
            AppResult[] results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"));
            app.Screenshot("Welcome screen.");

            Assert.IsTrue(results.Any());
        }


         [Test]
        public void ParseFromString()
        {
            Ingredient ingr = new Ingredient();
            ingr.TryToParseFromString("Ingredients");
            Assert.AreEqual(0, ingr.Amount, "amount problem");
            Assert.AreEqual(null, ingr.Item, "item problem");
            Assert.AreEqual(null, ingr.Units, "units problem");
            Assert.AreEqual("Ingredients", ingr.Unparsed, "unparsed problem");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using NUnit?

Comment: Yes, I am using UNit

Comment: Have you investigated the error you get? The compatibility may suggest that cookbook is only compatible with android code.

Comment: I did looked at the error in google, but find nothing helpful. What do you mean by "only compatible with android code"?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? maybe this link might help https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/51749/package-x-is-not-compatible-with-net461-netframeworkversionv461.aspx.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning, rebuilding, or closing the program?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're mixing up the concept of unit tests and UI tests since you have both in your test project. What you should do is create two separate projects, for example `Cookbook.UITests` and `Cookbook.UnitTests`. The reason is that UI Tests are meant to emulate user behavior while being run on an emulator, real device or perhaps a cloud testing service. Unit tests, on the other hand, should test stuff like the business logic of your code application (to put it simply).

What I would suggest you to do is the following:

1. Create the two separate projects `Cookbook.UITests` and `Cookbook.UnitTests`
2. Follow the [great guidance by SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939217/6625726) on how to set up the unit test project.
3. Follow the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-xamarin-forms) by Microsoft to set up the UITest project.